# Homework, Python 3: Changing a Variable Type From Within a Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

For part of an assignment I need to return variables from one function as a string. I then need to take those variables and put them through another function, finally returning those same variables as integers. I hope this isn't too vague. This seems like something that would have been easy enough to find on my own, but it's been about an hour of searching.

`startHour` and `startMinute` are the variables I would like to convert.

Here are the functions in question:

```
hoursList = []
minutesList = []
listSize = 0

def createList(listSize): #WORKING
    while listSize < 24:
        hoursList.append(listSize)
        listSize += 1
    while listSize < 84:
        minutesList.append(listSize - 24)
        listSize += 1

createList(listSize)

def collectUserInputTime(): #WORKING
    startHour, startMinute = input("Enter the time the call starts in 24-hour rotation:\n").split(":")
    return startHour, startMinute

def validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute): #NEED TO CHANGE STRING TO INT
    if int(startHour) in hoursList and int(startMinute) in minutesList:
        #print("PASS")
        return True, int(startHour), int(startMinute)
    else:
        print("FAIL")
        return False

startHour, startMinute = collectUserInputTime()
validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)
```

I also tried:

```
return startHours = int(startHour), startMinute = int(startMinute)
```

How shall I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: what is hourlist and minutelist, add it in the code, not here.

Comment: How are you calling these functions? You do know that `collectionUserInputTime` is returning back a tuple?

Comment: Added the full code

Comment: Now that you've added the full code, you should explain more as to what is not working?

Comment: You code is right. I get the correct answer both int.

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus Sorry, I'm just so new to this. Is it an issue or does it matter that when I print out the type, that it still shows up as "str"?

Comment: @Miket25 Apparently what I've done is correct, so I guess I just don't understand why when I print out the type after the fact, that it shows up as "str".

Comment: Are you reassigning the return values back into `startHour` and `startMinute`?

Comment: change the last sentence to    T_F,startHour, startMinute=validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code correctly returns integer values from `validateUserInputTime`:

```
return True, int(startHour), int(startMinute)
```

But when you call the function, you ignore those return values:

```
validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)
```

… so it doesn't matter that they're correct; you aren't doing anything with them.

If you then try to `print(type(startHour))`, it will still be `str`, because it's still a name for the same value it's always been.

If you want to assign those return values to your variables, you need an assignment statement:

```
success, startHour, startMinute = validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)
```

And now, `print(type(startHour))` will show `int`.

---

However, this is a very weird interface for a function. If it succeeds, you return `True` plus two values; if it fails, you return `False` plus nothing else. So, for invalid times, that assignment is going to raise a `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

You could fix this by returning three values even in the failure case:

```
return False, int(startHour), int(startMinute)
```

Or, maybe more simply, just use a single `return`:

```
success = int(startHour) in hoursList and int(startMinute) in minutesList
if not success:
    print("FAIL")
return success, int(startHour), int(startMinute)
```

Comment: That assignment statement was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

it is getting converted just you can't figure it out your function `validateUserInputTime()` is returning values in integer format just you are not displaying it using print statement

use this code:

```
hoursList = []
minutesList = []
listSize = 0

def createList(listSize): #WORKING
    while listSize < 24:
        hoursList.append(listSize)
        listSize += 1
    while listSize < 84:
        minutesList.append(listSize - 24)
        listSize += 1

createList(listSize)

def collectUserInputTime(): #WORKING
    startHour, startMinute = input("Enter the time the call starts in 24-hour rotation:\n").split(":")
    return startHour, startMinute

def validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute):
    if int(startHour) in hoursList and int(startMinute) in minutesList:
        #print("PASS")
        return True, int(startHour), int(startMinute)
    else:
        print("FAIL")
        return False

startHour, startMinute = collectUserInputTime()
print(validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute))
```